# How do I make a script that selects all-but-one items in duplicate groups?

Tags: applescript, selection

It is possible to use AppleScript in Media Pro, and I am using it to catalog all my images, but now I am trying to develop a script that will select all `media items` except the first `media item whose name is not in my_list_of_unique_short_names`.

I have been looking at some of the example scripts that it ships with and at the Documentation, but at the moment I seem to be stuck and run into different issues regarding access-rights, vectors and media item selection depending on what parts of the code I change.

```
on run
    tell window 1 of application "Media Pro"
        activate
        set my_listunique to {}
        set my_listall to the selection of catalog 1 of application "Media Pro"
        repeat with my_item in my_listall
            if my_item is not in my_listunique then
                set end of my_listunique to my_item
            end if
        end repeat
        try
            select (every media item in my_listall whose name is not in my_listunique)
        on error
            select {}
        end try
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: You should take a look at your `select` statement. `my_listunique` is filled with `media items`, but your filtering as if the list is filled with `name` properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Applescript, you can't do this:

```
select (every media item in my_listall whose name is not in my_listunique)
```

You are unable to use a `whose` clause to filter a list. Instead, you have two options.

**Filter the list in a repeat loop**

```
set media_select to {}
repeat with i from 1 to (count my_listall)
    if name of item i of my_listall is not in my_listunique
        set end of media_select to item i of my_listall
    end
end
```

**Let the application filter for you**

```
tell window 1 of application "Media Pro"
    select every media item whose name is not in my_listunique
end
```